# Unable to import service in angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-services

I'm struggling with importing a simple service in angular2. Please help me rectify the problem. I know I'm missing something very simple but can't find it.
Thanks in advance

http://plnkr.co/edit/Yrh9gC8BMZdtUwy947Za?p=preview

```
//our root app component
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core'
import {DataService} from './app.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [DataService],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>

    </div>
  `,

})
export class App implements OnInit{
  constructor(service: DataService) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    console.log(this.service) // prints Undefined here
   this.name = this.service.setName('test');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to tell your constructor what kind of a service it is.  For example "public" or "private".

```
constructor(public service: DataService) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
```

This is essentially, what can see this service, can only this class see this service?  If so do private, otherwise do public.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this, plunker, is what you are looking for,

### <kbd>[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/tZRJOV2BcLCixodQ0LQM?p=preview)</kbd>

if so you can change

```
import {Component, OnInit} from 'angular2/core'
import {DataService} from './app.service'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  providers: [DataService],
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
      
    </div>
  `,
  
})
export class App implements OnInit{
  constructor(public service: DataService) {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    
    this.service.setName('test');
    this.name = this.service.getName();
    
    console.log(this.service.getName());
  }

}
```